# Where clause from array column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column with value `["NONCODE","OFFCR", "SPVR", "CORD"]` inside.

I want to return a value when one of the values ​​in the column matches.

```sql
Select * from table where column='SPVR' --will be true or return the values
Select * from table where column='MGR' --will be false or return an empty values
```

In that field column, I have value

```
["NONCODE","OFFCR", "SPVR", "CORD"]
["NONCODE","OFFCR", "SPVR", "CORD"]
["ASST-MGR"]
["ASST-MGR"]
["MGR"]
["MGR"]
```

If I query

```sql
Select * from table where column='SPVR'
```

the result shows the only row contain 'SPVR'

```sql
Select * from table where column='MGR'
```

the result shows the only row contain 'MGR' (the row with 'ASST-MGR' do not appear)

If I use the 'LIKE' command, all the rows containing MGR will appear

Comment: Have you tried [like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: What is your SQL Server version and what exactly is the column value - `["NONCODE","OFFCR", "SPVR", "CORD"]` or just `"NONCODE","OFFCR", "SPVR", "CORD"` ? Thanks.

Comment: SQL Server does not support arrays. What is the data type of that column?

Comment: nvarchar for the datatype

Comment: @FajarTaufik . . . None of your queries will return a match, because they do not take `'['` and `'"'` into account.  It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: You (and others) will forever struggle to get useful information from this column because of the poor choice to store multiple values in one column. That is a basic design flaw and you should reconsider the decisions leading to this choice if possible.

Comment: Yes, finally I made a separate table to achieve this. thank you for all the responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original answer:**

If you use SQL Server 2016+, you may try to parse this data using `OPENJSON()` function, because `["NONCODE","OFFCR", "SPVR", "CORD"]` is a valid `JSON` array. [OPENJSON()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#return-value) is a table-valued function that parses `JSON` text, so you can use any set-based approach to get your expected results.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data(
   [Text] varchar(100)
) 
INSERT INTO #Data
   ([Text]) 
VALUES
   ('["NONCODE","OFFCR", "SPVR", "CORD"]'),
   ('["NONCODE","OFFCR", "SPVR", "CORD"]'),
   ('["ASST-MGR"]'),
   ('["ASST-MGR"]'),
   ('["MGR"]'),
   ('["MGR"]')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM #Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.[Text]) j
WHERE j.[value] = 'SPVR'
-- or, if needed:
-- WHERE j.[value] LIKE '%MGR%'
```

Output:

```
-----------------------------------
Text
-----------------------------------
["NONCODE","OFFCR", "SPVR", "CORD"]
["NONCODE","OFFCR", "SPVR", "CORD"]
```

**Update:**

For SQL Server 2012, you may try to split the data using XML:

```
SELECT 
   t.[Text]
FROM (
   SELECT 
      [Text],
      CAST(CONCAT('<x>', REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([Text], '[', ''), ']', ''), ' ', ''), ',', '</x><x>'), '</x>') AS xml) AS XMLText
   FROM #Data
) t
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT N.value('.', 'varchar(100)') AS [value] 
   FROM t.XMLText.nodes('x') AS x(N)
) c
WHERE c.[value] = '"SPVR"'
```

Comment: unfortunately, I used SQL Server 2012

Comment: @FajarTaufik See updated answer. Using `XML` is an option here. Thanks.

Comment: Wowsome, you are correct, this is the answer, thank you for your response.

Answer (score 4):

While your current structure is not ideal and you should avoid storing CSV data into regular SQL columns, we can try the following workaround:

```
SELECT array_col
FROM yourTable
WHERE array_col LIKE '%' + '"SPVR"' + '%';
```

### Demo

Note: SQL Server (at least currently) does not support a native array type.  One workaround would be to use temporary tables or table-valued parameters.

Comment: I can't really improve much upon my original answer.  You should move away from storing CSV and improve your table design IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new string_split() tsql function to split your csv values into individual values. This was introduced in SQL 2016 (compatibility level 130). Eg below:

```
CREATE TABLE #myTable(vals varchar(100)) 
INSERT INTO #myTable(vals) 
VALUES('"NONCODE","OFFCR","SPVR","CORD"'), ('"NON","CODE", "PACE", "RACE"')

SELECT *
FROM #myTable CROSS APPLY string_split(vals, ',')
WHERE value = '"SPVR"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to given answer, I'd suggest `charindex` in this scenario:

```
SELECT array_col
FROM yourTable
WHERE CHARINDEX("SPVR", array_col) > 0
```